# Is static variable gets re-initialized when the code is in a shared library?

Tags: c++, c

I have this code:

file1.cpp

```
int foo()
{
   static bool b = false;

   ... more code ...
}
```

This file compiles to a shared library, `libfoo.so` and this library is linked to an application.

My question is, when the application restarts - it gets killed and started by system - the static variables are re-initialized, am I right?

Another words, after each application re-start, at first time running to function foo(), b's value is false.

Comment: Yes. Upon application termination it's entire memory space is freed so any globals/statics can't persist

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername Answers go in the answers section. Not in comments.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't feel this qualifies for a full-fledged answer. You're welcome to elaborate and post an answer

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername - Short does not mean incomplete or inadequate.  [Terse in fact often suggests elegance](https://copyblogger.com/ernest-hemingway-top-5-tips-for-writing-well/).  I think others will agree, up-votes will follow.